# I'm trying to run my flutter app on an emulator from VS code and I get an error saying it cannot find the path to my main.dart file

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I want to run my flutter program on an emulator from VS Code. The idea is that when I run a debug session in VS Code, the app should appear on the emulator. I have the emulator open and connected to VS Code, however, when I try to debug I get an error that says "Error: Error when reading 'bin/main.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.
".

```
**This is my launch.json file in VS Code**

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Dart",
            "program": "bin/main.dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        }
    ]
}
```

The path to my flutter app is ...wordpair_generator\lib\main.dart so I tried changing the JSON file code to the following

```
"program": "lib/main.dart",
```

I received an error saying "Error: Error when reading 'lib/main.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.
" so I then tried changing the JSON file to the following

```
"program": "wordpair_generator/lib/main.dart"
```

Now I don't get an error, the debug runs, but nothing happens. My app does not appear on my emulator.

**UPDATE**
I left the program running while I left to make tea, and the program worked on the emulator. If anyone is having a similar issue, I would recommend letting the program run for about 5 minutes. Now whenever I run the program it only takes about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are not solving that issue by making tea imao.

Try to change it into
`"program": "${workspaceFolder}/lib/main.dart",`

You may open the `wordpair_generator` folder in vscode, so that `${workspaceFolder}` resolves to that.

For more info you are welcome to look at [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

> ${workspaceFolder} - the path of the folder opened in VS Code

For others trying to figure out the correct `launch.json`, actually you could just press F5 on the main.dart (ensure you have flutter extension installed and no existing `launch.json`), then you may find the plugin automatically set for you. That's the lazy way.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `.vscode/launch.json` file and run, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Remember to change your program path to your file path.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Dart & Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    }
]
```

}